# Why is there no syntax highlighting for Haxe code on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxe

[image: Just white text]

I don't understand why VS Code has no syntax highlighting for my Haxe code. I tried going through settings, and I can't figure it out. What's wrong?

Comment: I searched for the file extension on Google: _"An HX file is a source code file used by programs written in the Haxe programming language. It contains code written using extended ECMAScript syntax."_ - Have you installed the Haxe language support extension?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are working with `.hx` file type which is for Haxe programming language. You need to install the extension in VS Code to support this. It can be downloaded from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nadako.vshaxe

Comment: Oh, right I forgot about that! Thanks, it works now.